# why it is showing " Error: Could not find or load main class simple" when running in command prompt

Tags: java, command-prompt

```
class Simple{  
    public static void main(String [] args){  
         System.out.println("Hello Java");  
    }  
}
```

Running this program using command prompt:

`javac Simple.java` - compiled it successfully,

`java Simple` - shows error `"Error: Could not find or load main class simple"`

What are the reasons for showing this error?

I  have set,

JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241, 

path- %JAVA_HOME%\bin, 

CLASSPATH - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: From the message "Error: Could not find or load main class **simple**" I suspect you are actually executing `java simple` instead of `java Simple` . Otherwise the message would have been "Error: Could not find or load main class **Simple**". These Java commands are **not** case insensitive.

Comment: No. i am using java Simple @EugenCovaci

Comment: Check if the folder has any `simple` compiled class also. Delete all *.class files in the directory and run again

Comment: I read that post already, not helping me...@Binu

Comment: I did that already @RahulAgrawal  Now I found out that it works fine when I used notepad to write my code. But, why it shows an error when I used notepad++ to write the same code?

Comment: Is this the whole file or does it contain other code also??

Comment: whole file @RahulAgrawal

Comment: show the results of 'dir' command on that directory

Comment: @RahulAgrawal
 Directory of C:\Users\CG-DTE\Desktop\NPTEL\Java\java program

25-01-2020  12.19 PM    <DIR>          .
25-01-2020  12.19 PM    <DIR>          ..
25-01-2020  12.19 PM               416 Simple.class
25-01-2020  12.18 PM               117 Simple.java
               2 File(s)            533 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  69,581,066,240 bytes free

Comment: Shouldn't the evn. variable PATH be in caps?? Try 1. echo $PATH 2.) echo $JAVA_HOME

Comment: *"CLASSPATH - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin"* - That is incorrect.  And possibly the cause of the problem.   This is *explained* in the Q&A that Binu linked to.  But unfortunately it is necessary to read the main answer (preferably *all of it*) to get the information you need.

Comment: For the record, setting CLASSPATH to that directory tells the `java` command to look only there for your ".class" files.  Obviously, they are not there ... so Java says it cannot find them.  You probably should set `CLASSPATH` to `.` in this case.  Or better still unset it completely.